# "gift to me" vs "gift for me"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I need some help with this, I a learner of English and I want to know which of this two sentece is better to use: ***nice gift to me*** or ***nice gift for me.***

Comment: Both can be correct, depending on what you are trying to say.  Could you please edit your question to provide more detail?

Comment: "nice gift for me" is the more common expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should realize:

#### You ask which sentence is correct, but you have not provided any sentence.

(Neither "nice gift to me" nor "nice gift for me" is complete sentence.)

That's part of the problem, because which preposition is better to use might well depend on the verb in the sentence.

For example, I might say:

> My wife bought a nice gift for me.

I wouldn't say that she "bought a nice gift *to* me" because we don't buy things ***to*** someone, we buy things ***for*** someone.

Similarly, I might also say:

> My wife gave a nice gift to me.

because we give gifts ***to*** people, not ***for*** people; therefore, the word "for" is not appropriate there.

However, let's say I woke up one morning and find a nicely-wrapped gift on my kitchen counter. It has a tag that says, "To J.R." In that case, I could say either one of these:

> I glanced at the tag on the present, and found a nice gift to me.
>
> I glanced at the tag on the present, and found a nice gift for me.

When a gift is *to* someone, it's also *for* that same person, so either word can work.